# Retrieve Cases with CaseHistories in One Query

Tags: soql, case

I expected the following query is valid:

```
SELECT ID, Subject, Type, (SELECT Field, OldValue, NewValue FROM CaseHistories)
FROM Case
```

But I get `Didn't understand relationship 'CaseHistories'` error. I can query `SELECT Field, OldValue, NewValue FROM CaseHistories` in a separate request.

Is this possible to retrieve cases and their histories in one query?

Comment: you can always use describe call to check the relationship name http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/117054/18731

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The child history relationship name is called "histories".
Try the following query:

```
SELECT ID, Subject, Type, (SELECT Field, OldValue, NewValue FROM Histories)
FROM Case
```

Comment: thanks Mark, where can I find how specific relationship is called?

Comment: I found Relationship Name in Force.com IDE, is there any other tool where I can quick check the name? Maybe I can find it in Salesforce UI? Salesforce Schema Builder doesn't have one.

Comment: You can identify parent-child relationships by viewing Entity Relationship Diagrams (ERD) or by examining the enterprise WSDL for your organization. But probably the most reliable method for identifying relationships is to execute a describeSObjects() call. You can use the AJAX Toolkit to quickly execute test calls.